# Spring Boot validator does`t work properly

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have encountered such a problem that the validator does not see the data that I transmit in the body.

```
WARN 4088 --- [io-28852-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<account.entitys.User> account.controllers.Authentication.singUp(account.entitys.User) with 2 errors: [Field error in object 'user' on field 'password': rejected value [null]; codes [NotEmpty.user.password,NotEmpty.password,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.password,password]; arguments []; default message [password]]; default message [must not be empty]] [Field error in object 'user' on field 'lastname': rejected value []; codes [NotEmpty.user.lastname,NotEmpty.lastname,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.lastname,lastname]; arguments []; default message [lastname]]; default message [must not be empty]] ]
```

Controller:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@Controller()
public class Authentication {

    ArrayList<User> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostMapping("signup")
    public ResponseEntity<User> singUp(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        data.add(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

User:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.*;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;


@Data
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastname;
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;
    @JsonIgnore
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;
}
```

Json:

```
{"name":"John","lastname":"Doe","email":"johndoe@acme.com","password":"secret"}
```

Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
implementation group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.1.0.Final'
```

I am a beginner, I don't have enough experience and this is the first time I have encountered such a problem. If I don't use a validator then everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both `@JsonIgnore` and `@NotEmpty` on the field `password`. The first annotation will tell spring to ignore the value for the field password, thus `password` will always remain `null`. This will cause the `@NotEmpty` validation rule to always fail. Remove `@JsonIgnore` and try again.

Comment: God, it's not my attention, I wanted the password field to be ignored in response. Thanks!

Comment: @CalmPerson you can achieve that by annotating your `User` class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "password", allowSetters = true)`.  When `allowSetters` is set to `true` it means spring will not ignore the value of `password` during `deserialization` (when request is transformed into `User` object) but _will_  ignore `password` during `serialization` (when `User` object is serialized into a `Http response`). So remove `@JsonIgnore` and replace it with `@JsonIgnoreProperties` at the class level to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

Remove annotation @JsonIgnore on fied password.and restart your project.

Answer (score 0):

try to create a new entity such as UserCreateRequest and put this validation annotation to here. Then call it in your signup api's request body